# What is the best approach for using Mixpanel People with Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

Here is the official documentation.. 
https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript#user-identity

The documentation explains how this works, but I am having trouble figuring out the best way to handle this with Magento. It seems like every way I think to implement it, it makes redundant people definitions.

Comment: Yeah i need some help here also

Comment: I installed [arush-mixpanel](https://github.com/arush/arush-mixpanel) but it seems that just add the library :(

Comment: I'm using an extension by Tegdesign: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-analytics-with-mixpanel.html